# Is it worth to reindex when migrating from lucene 3.x to 4.x

Tags: lucene, indexing, migration

I am going to migrate Lucene version from 3.5 to 4.7.
And as my index is really huge I am wondering if it is worth to reindex it.
Mostly I am interested if it is worth in case of performance.
Any suggestions?

Regards

Comment: please provide more details on what schema is, which component did you use, which types of queries?

Answer (score 2):

As usual, there is no simple answer to this.

The big change is that in v4.0 Lucene has introduced the ability to provide custom codec/postings format. Michael McCandless (one of the Lucene authors), [explains the difference between 3.X and 4.0](http://blog.mikemccandless.com/2010/06/lucenes-pulsingcodec-on-primary-key.html):

> By default, Lucene uses the StandardCodec, which writes and reads in
>   nearly the same format as the current stable branch (3.x). Details for
>   a given term are stored in terms dictionary files, while the docs and
>   positions where that term occurs are stored in separate files.

That said, there are different codecs and each of them focuses on different things.

[This presentation](http://www.slideshare.net/LucidImagination/flexible-indexing-in-lucene-40) covers some posting formats and has some insights which format is tuned for which scenario. If you are going to stay with `StandardCodec`, I'd guess you won't gain much choosing to reindex.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using IndexUpgrader of 4.7 to upgrade your index as there are some changes in the index format (postings format to be precise) from 3.x to 4.x. Default Codec for Lucene 4.7 may not be able to read the index files of Lucene 3.x

IndexUpgrader is a utility provided by Lucene.
http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_7_0/core/org/apache/lucene/index/IndexUpgrader.html